# Node.js Express not able to get static files and route is deeper then one folder level

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

Before I ask the question here is the folder structure of my node.js express app:

`/home
    server.js
    index.html
    /app
        /routes
            public.js
    /public
        /css
            main.css`

This is what I have in `server.js`:

```
// ROUTING FOR STATIC CONTENT
var public_dir = __dirname + '/public';
app.use(express.static(public_dir));

// INITIALIZE ROUTER
var public_router = express.Router();

// IMPORT PUBLIC ROUTES
require('./app/routes/public')(public_router, public_dir);

// REGISTER ROUTES
app.use('/', public_router);
```

This is what I have in `/app/routes/public.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(public_router, public_dir) {

    public_router.get('/new', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(public_dir, 'index.html'));
    });

    public_router.get('/popular', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(public_dir, 'index.html'));
    });

    public_router.get('/popular/today', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(public_dir, 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

Inside `index.html` I call css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

**The problem:**

When I visit **mydomain.com/new** and **mydomain.com/popular**, css file is loaded and page is rendered properly. However when I visit **mydomain.com/popular/today**, css file is not loaded properly. In chrome dev tools I see that browser is trying to load css from popular folder which is incorrect.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools]

Any ideas or comments would be appriciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">`.

Note the prefixing `/`. This will make the browser to start search in the root of the tree instead of using relative paths.

Comment: You my friend are indeed correct! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Thanks @Sawny, nothing else worked for me. Have been looking for a solution for past 2 days.